# How do I permanently remove a previous Mii from a 3DS when it is not in the Mii Plaza?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I brought a second-hand 3DS and when in the Mii Plaza, I am the only character, the favorite.  **But** when I play *Mario Kart 7*, all the accolades show as the previous owner's Mii even though her Mii is not to be found.  How do I get the previous owner's Mii out of the system, and set all games to use my Mii?

Answer (score 1):

Open up *Mii Maker*, select the button that says **View Mii Characters**, then tap on the Mii you want to get rid of and choose **Erase**. If it is possible to get rid of the Mii you don't want, this should do it.

Comment: No I tried to do that but the old mii is not represented in the mii plaza. Wierd huh? I am thinking it may be in the sd cards memory???

Comment: I'm confused. I thought you *wanted* the old mii to not show up anywhere, including the Mii Plaza

Comment: Could it be that the Mii is alive only in the savegame for Mario Kart 7? Perhaps the answer lies there?

Comment: I agree with skovacs1. Maybe it's just that your old mii is only playable with the save data of your old 3ds, not with this second hand one.